# How do I integrate $\frac1{x^2+x+1}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have tried this:

$$\frac1{x^2+x+1} = \frac1{\left( (x+\frac12)^2+\frac34\right)}$$

Now $u = x+\frac12$

$$\frac1{  u^2+\frac34 }$$ Now multiply by $ \frac34$

$$\frac1{ \frac43 u^2 + 1}$$

Now put the $\frac43$ outside the integral

$$\frac34 \int \frac1{u^2+1}\,du=\frac34\arctan(u)=\frac34\arctan(x+1/2)$$

But the result is not the same result calculated by computers.

What did I do wrong?

Could someone please help me with this?

I don't know where my wrong calculation is. The way should be correct to get to the result.

Edit:

So now

$\int \frac{1}{x^2+x+1}=\int \frac{1}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2}= \int \frac{4}{3} \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+1}$
u=x^2+1/2
$\int \frac{4}{3} \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}(u)^2+1}$

$\int \frac{4}{3} \frac{1}{\frac{4u^2}{3}+1}$

$\int \frac{4}{3} \frac{1}{\frac{2u^2}{\sqrt{3}}+1}$

Now it is:

$\frac{4}{3} \int \frac{1}{\frac{2u^2}{\sqrt{3}}+1}$

$=\frac{4}{3} * arctan(2*(x^2+1/2)/(\sqrt{3}))$

Why is this still not the same as the computer calculated solution?

Comment: Please use MathJax to render your math equations

Comment: $\dfrac1{u^2+\frac34}$ is not the same as $\dfrac1{\frac43u^2+1}$, which is not the same as $\dfrac34\dfrac1{u^2+1}$ (try $u=0$, for example)

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya how do I use mathjax here? I just know LaTex

Comment: @Rapiz go here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also MathJax is almost same as LaTeX except some differences that you will come across if you continue to use MathJax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{1}{u^2+3/4}=\frac{1}{\frac34((2u/\sqrt 3)^2+1)}=\frac43 \frac{1}{v^2+1}$$

where $v=2u/\sqrt 3$.  Can you finish now?

Comment: This is the thing I don't understand. It is used in the videos about this fraction but it does not make sense for me. Why can't I multiply the lower term by 4/3 ? and put it outside the integral? And why is this equal to the right term? I don't get how to get from the left to the right.

Comment: You can multiply both numerator and denominator by $4/3$.  But that leaves $4u^2/3+1$ in the denominator.  Then let $v=2u/\sqrt 3$.  Do you have it now?

Comment: I would do it like this : $$\frac{1}{u^2+3/4} | * \frac{1}{\frac{4}{3}} = \frac{1}{4/3*u^2 + 1}$$  How do you get the second term? Could you explain this? ^^

Comment: Again we have $$\frac1{u^2+3/4}=\frac{4/3}{4/3}\frac1{u^2+3/4}=\frac{4/3}{4u^2/3+1}=\frac43 \frac1{(2u/\sqrt 3)^2+1}$$

Comment: @Rapiz Multiplying top and bottom by $4/3$ gives $\frac{4}{3} \frac{1}{(4/3) u^2+1}$. You can't just multiply the bottom alone by $4/3$, that would change the result.

Comment: @ian I believe that I wrote it correctly.

Comment: @MarkViola Yep, you're good.

Comment: But the multiplication should not effect the upper term? This should just multiply the lower term to get the 1 ? With this it is $\frac{1}{4/3*u^2+1}$ and we could rewind this after the result of the integral or not?

Comment: @Rapiz No, because now you've changed the integrand, that's what I was trying to say. If you want to multiply the bottom by $4/3$ (so as to make the $3/4$ into a $1$ without factoring the way that Mark Viola did) then you have to do the same to the top.

Comment: Anyways I get the point of this way. How do you get the $(2u/\sqrt(3)^2)$ ?

Comment: Is the ratio $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a}{(4/3)b}$?  It isn't.  But we can write $$\frac ab=\frac{(4/3)a}{(4/3)b}$$

Comment: Note that $(2u/\sqrt 3)^2=4u^2/3$.

Comment: Ratio? You mean if this is equal?  No. My try was to redo this change of the integrand with the same way we do in substitutions

Comment: Thanks!!!!! So to reform it in a x^2 we do this and have the arctan form! Jesus

Comment: You cannot simply multiply the denominator by $4/3$ and not do the same to the numerator.  The integrand IS a ratio.  It is $\frac1{u^2+3/4}$.  So, here $a=1$ and $b=u^2+3/4$.  Now how can we preserve equality?  We can multiply by $1=\frac{4/3}{4/3}$.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Pleased you have it now.

Comment: I know it is not the same but in integrals we often do such things to change the value to a form and redo this change later? Or are we just using *1 stuff so just changing the form. I think in my calc1 lectures for integrals we did such stuff in substitution.

Comment: One thing why does the result differ? With this it is 4/3 * arctan ((2x+1)/sqrt(3)) or not?

Comment: I get $$\frac2{\sqrt 3} \arctan\left( \frac{2x+1}{\sqrt 3}\right) $$

Comment: How did you do this? ^^ 2/sqrt(3) ?

Comment: Follow the substitution $v=2u/\sqrt 3$.  Note that $dv =\frac 2{\sqrt 3} \,du$.  And $\frac43 \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}=??$

Comment: Ah well yeah nevermind. Thanks forgot about that

Comment: It's OK to make mistakes.  That's how we learn and improve.  Hang in there.